# Make width of seaborn facets proportional to the range of data along the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have used `FacetGrid()` from the `seaborn` module to break a line graph into segments with labels for each region as the title of each subplot. I saw the option in the documentation to have the x-axes be independent. However, I could not find anything related to having the plot sizes correspond to the size of each axis.

The code I used to generate this plot, along with the plot, are found below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Added during Edit 1.
sns.set()

graph = sns.FacetGrid(rmsf_crys, col = "Subunit", sharex = False)
graph.map(plt.plot, "Seq", "RMSF")
graph.set_titles(col_template = '{col_name}')

plt.show()
```

**Plot resulting from the above code**
[image: 1]

**Edit 1**

Updated plot code using `relplot()` instead of calling `FacetGrid()` directly. The final result is the same graph.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Forgot to include this in the original code snippet.
sns.set()

graph = sns.relplot(data = rmsf_crys, x = "Seq", y = "RMSF", 
                    col = "Subunit", kind = "line", 
                    facet_kws = dict(sharex=False))
graph.set_titles(col_template = '{col_name}')

plt.show()
```

Comment: A [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) is a figure level plot and all the plots sizes are determined by `height` and `aspect` of the figure. Update to the current version of seaborn, which is 0.11.2. Also, you should be using [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) with `kind='line'`, as using `FacetGrid` directly, is discouraged.

Comment: I think it's a little unclear what you're asking, but is the idea that you want the width of each subplot to be proportional to the range of x values in that facet?

Comment: @mwaskom That's exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thank you for the heads up. Made the corresponding edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full support for this would need to live at the matplotlib layer, and I don't believe it's currently possible to have independent axes but shared transforms. (Someone with deeper knowledge of the matplotlib scale internals may prove me wrong).

But you can get pretty close by calculating the x range you'll need ahead of time and using that to parameterize the gridspec for the facets:

```py
import numpy as np, seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
xranges = tips.groupby("size")["total_bill"].agg(np.ptp)
xranges *= 1.1  # Account for default margins
sns.relplot(
    data=tips, kind="line",
    x="total_bill", y="tip",
    col="size", col_order=xranges.index,
    height=3, aspect=.65,
    facet_kws=dict(sharex=False, gridspec_kws=dict(width_ratios=xranges))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was after.